# PhP regex for a string, what would be the best way to do it?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array with `rule` field that has a string like this:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=3FR
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=3SA
FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20170728T080000Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20170527T100000Z;BYDAY=4SA
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=TH
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH
FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20170610T085959Z;BYDAY=SA
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=2TH
```

Each line is a different array, I am giving a few clues to get an idea of what I need.

What I need is to write a regex that would take off all unnecessary values.

So, I don't need FREQ= ; BYDAY= etc. I basically need the values after = but each one I want to store in a different variable.

Taking third one as an example it would be:

```
$frequency = WEEKLY
$until = 20170728T080000Z
$day = MO, TU, WE, TH, FR
```

It doesn't have to be necessarily one regex, there can be one regex for each value. So I have one for FREQ:

```
preg_match("/[^FREQ=][A-Z]+/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

But I can't do it for the rest unfortunately, how can I solve this?

Comment: Nooooo, not explode(). preg_split() is the Solution!

Comment: could you provide an solution then if preg_split should be used?, as far as I am aware preg_split will give an array of results and remember that each value has to go to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice: For this problem, I recommend the generell approach @revo posted, it's concise and safe and easy on the eyes -- but keep in mind, that regular expressions come with a performance penalty compared to fixed string functions, so if you can use strpos/substr/explode/..., try to use them, don't 'knee-jerk' to a preg_-based solution.

Since the seperators are fixed and don't seem to occur in the values your are interested in, and you furthermore rely on knowledge of the keys (FREQ:, etc) you don't need regular-expressions (as much as  I like to use them anywhere I can, and you can use them here); why not simply explode and split in this case?

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(';', $line);
    $frequency = $until = $day = $interval = null;
    foreach($parts as $part) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
        switch($key) {
             case 'FREQ':
                   $frequency = $value;
                   break;
             case 'INTERVAL':
                   $interval = $value;
                   break;
              // and so on
         }
    }
    doSomethingWithTheValues();
}
```

This may be more readable and efficient if your use-case is as simple as stated.

Comment: That seems to be the best solution, it works and I assume if a variable is empty it would ignore it and go on

Answer (score 2):

The only way to go would be PHP array destructuring:

```
$str = "FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20170728T080000Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR";

preg_match_all('~(\w+)=([^;]+)~', $str, $matches);
[$freq, $until, $byday] = $matches[2]; // As of PHP 7.1 (otherwise use list() function)
echo $freq, " ", $until, " ", $byday;
// WEEKLY 20170728T080000Z MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/T2UhW)

### Be more general

Using [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+)=([^;]+)~', $str, $m);
$m[1] = array_map('strtolower', $m[1]);
$vars = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
extract($vars);
echo $freq, " ", $until, " ", $byday;
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/niter)

Comment: I like this, but the data is not well formed per the OPs example -- so this does not solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I get unexpected '=' the one just before matches

Comment: *...data is not well formed* I don't get it, @TomRegner.

Comment: well I have php 7.1 so that shouldn't be a problem, for @TomRegner comment, it is right, you specify one string. I have an array of 976 of those

Comment: @revo Not every line contains the same kind of data, sometimes there is UNTIL, sometimes not, etc. and AFAIU other comments, positions may vary as well

Comment: revos Solutions is imho the best one.  And I consider my Answer as good Answer too. So you have two Ways you can make it. But you can not expect to solve all Problems with writing just one Line of Code. And you can not expect, that we do your Work. You have to go for good Input-Data. Then the Scripts become easier for you. If you have sh!tty Data, then you need to expect more Effort in Programming. That's logic, isn't it? Show some more Effort please.

Comment: Thats cool ! If the green arrow can be moved, move it here please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Pattern

```
;?[A-Z]+=
```

together with preg_split();

```
preg_split('/;?[A-Z]+=/', $str);
```

Explanation

```
;       match Semikolon
?       no or one of the last Character
[A-Z]+  match one or more uppercase Letters
=       match one =
```

If you want to have each Line into a seperate Array, you should do it this Way:

```
 # split each Line into an Array-Element
 $lines = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $str);

 # initiate Array for Results
 $results = array();

 # start Looping trough Lines
 foreach($lines as $line){

  # split each Line by the Regex mentioned above and
  # put the resulting Array into the Results-Array
  $results[] = preg_split('/;?[A-Z]+=/', $line);

 }
```

Comment: This is all good, but it gives me an array of values, how do I lopp throught it and save it to different variable? As each values goes to a different field in database

Comment: I updated the Answer. Thats all you can do with preg_split().

Comment: this gives me an array inside array, but unfortunately I need variables to save to database because I cannot go $data = ['frequency' => $results[1]] because frequency is sometimes in different array number